# Boost MPL Types Vs Templates

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I'm fairly new to Boost MPL (and meta programming in general) and I think I'm confused by the idea of templates vs types. A simple example I'm working with is trying to compute the length of a vector. The following compiles fine:

```
typedef mpl::vector_c< int, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 > myVector;

struct TestSize
{
    template <typename mySequence> struct apply
    {
        typedef mpl::size<mySequence> type;
    };
};

typedef TestSize::apply<myVector>::type result;
```

but if I add "::type" to the result of the size computation, like this:

```
struct TestSize
{
    template <typename mySequence> struct apply
    {
        typedef mpl::size<mySequence>::type type;
    };
};

typedef TestSize::apply<myVector>::type result;
```

then I get the error "error: nontype "boost::mpl::size::type [with Sequence=mySequence]" is not a type name".

Is this a situation where the template parameter is not deduced because it is in a nested namespace? Adding to my confusion is the fact that the following compiles:

```
struct TestSize
{
    template <typename mySequence> struct apply
    {
        typedef mpl::size<mySequence> type;
        typedef mpl::range_c<int, 0, type::type::value> myRange;
    };
};

typedef TestSize::apply<myVector>::type result;
typedef TestSize::apply<textureIndices>::myRange range;
```

Why can I do "type::type::value" there, but not "size< mySequence>::type" on the line before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having this error is because you need to use `typename` like this (in the inner `apply`):

```
struct TestSize
{
    template <typename mySequence> struct apply
    {
        typedef typename mpl::size<mySequence>::type type; // <-- here!
    };
};
```

The need for the `typename` in this context arises from the way compilers compile templates. When the template is initially pre-compiled, it needs to be sematically correct. However, compiler doesn't know (at this point) that `mpl::size<mySequence>::type` is indeed a type. At this point it doesn't know what `mySequence` is, and how `mpl::size` is specified for `mySequence`. And by default it assumes **it is not a type**. So you need to hint it.

And now your probably understand why `type::type::value` works fine - compiler by default thinks `value` is not a type, you are not trying to use it as a type, and compiler is happy. By the way, if you were to define `value` as a type for a certain specialization, you would have a funny compilation error if this specialization is used!

Comment: @user1777820, you just opened such a Pandora box! In short, the reason is that `mpl::size<T>::type` is a *template-dependent* name. Sematic of `type` would be different based on what `T` actually is - it could a be a function, a type, a variable... Anything. On the other hand, sematics of `size<T>` do not depend on `T` - no matter what `T` is, `size<T>` is one thing only  - it's a template instantiation of previously defined template class `size`. No ambiguity, so no need to hint.

Comment: I deleted my comment, as I was going to start a new question, so I'm adding it back for anyone reading this in the future. I was asking how the solution here, using the typename hint, differs from my first code example with the line "typedef mpl::size<mySequence> type;" which compiles fine. 

Thanks @SergeyA!